# ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm trying to implement this tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular

My implementation: [Github](https://github.com/rcbandit111/media_auth)

I updated the package dependencies to latest version. But when I start the project I get exception:

```
13:34:43.343 [main] INFO  EngineApplication[logStarting:55] - Starting EngineApplication v1.0 on ws-11820 with PID 56180 (C:\Users\plte1219\Desktop\CJM\media_auth\target\engine-1.0.jar started by plte1219 in C:\Users\plte1219\Desktop\CJM\media_auth)
13:34:43.347 [main] INFO  EngineApplication[logStartupProfileInfo:655] - The following profiles are active: local
13:34:46.239 [main] INFO  RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[registerRepositoriesIn:127] - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
13:34:46.289 [main] INFO  RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[registerRepositoriesIn:187] - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
13:34:46.299 [main] INFO  RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[registerRepositoriesIn:127] - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
13:34:46.301 [main] INFO  RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[registerRepositoriesIn:187] - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
13:34:48.008 [main] INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[postProcessAfterInitialization:335] - Bean 'contextProductionDatasource' of type [org.engine.context.ContextProductionDatasource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80cefca2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
13:34:48.192 [main] INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker[postProcessAfterInitialization:335] - Bean 'contextWarehouseDatasource' of type [org.engine.context.ContextWarehouseDatasource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f848a010] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
13:34:49.537 [main] INFO  TomcatWebServer[initialize:108] - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
13:34:49.551 [main] INFO  Http11NioProtocol[log:173] - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13:34:49.552 [main] INFO  StandardService[log:173] - Starting service [Tomcat]
13:34:49.552 [main] INFO  StandardEngine[log:173] - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
13:34:49.693 [main] INFO  [/engine][log:173] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
13:34:49.693 [main] INFO  ServletWebServerApplicationContext[prepareWebApplicationContext:285] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6128 ms
13:34:50.508 [main] INFO  LogHelper[logPersistenceUnitInformation:31] - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: DS1]
13:34:51.231 [main] INFO  Version[logVersion:44] - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.18.Final
13:34:51.979 [main] INFO  Version[<clinit>:49] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
13:34:53.126 [main] INFO  HikariDataSource[getConnection:110] - PRODUCTION_HIKARICP_CONNECTION_POOL - Starting...
13:34:53.427 [main] INFO  HikariDataSource[getConnection:123] - PRODUCTION_HIKARICP_CONNECTION_POOL - Start completed.
13:34:53.565 [main] INFO  Dialect[<init>:172] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
13:34:55.995 [main] INFO  JtaPlatformInitiator[initiateService:52] - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
13:34:57.676 [main] INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[buildNativeEntityManagerFactory:416] - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'DS1'
13:34:57.698 [main] INFO  LogHelper[logPersistenceUnitInformation:31] - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: DS2]
13:34:58.075 [main] INFO  HikariDataSource[getConnection:110] - WAREHOUSE_HIKARICP_CONNECTION_POOL - Starting...
13:34:58.081 [main] INFO  HikariDataSource[getConnection:123] - WAREHOUSE_HIKARICP_CONNECTION_POOL - Start completed.
13:34:58.082 [main] INFO  Dialect[<init>:172] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
13:34:58.432 [main] INFO  JtaPlatformInitiator[initiateService:52] - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
13:34:58.433 [main] INFO  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[buildNativeEntityManagerFactory:416] - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'DS2'
13:34:58.879 [main] WARN  JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration[openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor:220] - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
13:34:59.216 [main] INFO  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor[initialize:181] - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
13:35:00.069 [main] WARN  FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration[checkTemplateLocationExists:67] - Cannot find template location(s): [classpath:/templates/] (please add some templates, check your FreeMarker configuration, or set spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false)
13:35:01.188 [main] INFO  Http11NioProtocol[log:173] - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13:35:01.423 [main] WARN  i18n[registerProviders:150] - RESTEASY002145: NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load builtin provider org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider from jar:file:/C:/Users/plte1219/Desktop/CJM/media_auth/target/engine-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/resteasy-jackson2-provider-4.5.5.Final.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/core/messagebody/AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:514)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:422)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:416)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:415)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadFromParent(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.doLoadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.registerProviders(RegisterBuiltin.java:132)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.RegisterBuiltin.register(RegisterBuiltin.java:52)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:266)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:92)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:986)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.load(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:82)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1624)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:274)
        at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(TreeMap.java:2905)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.lambda$deferredLoadOnStartup$0(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:65)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.doWithThreadContextClassLoader(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:106)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.performDeferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatWebServer.java:305)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:216)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.engine.EngineApplication.main(EngineApplication.java:25)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.core.messagebody.AsyncBufferedMessageBodyWriter
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Where do you deploy your project (jBoss/WildFly version)? It seems an incompatibility version with a jboss provided class.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot project with the embedded Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I updated `resteasy-jackson2-provider` and that caused the problem.

Turned out I had to also update `resteasy-client` to the same version, not sure if it applies to your case, but I got rid of this error this way. In my case I updated to the latest (at the moment) 4.5.8.Final